# Using SharePoint to manage meeting requests.

Tags: calendar

At the moment we use outlook and sent meeting invites via email and they are added to our calendars automatically. Can invites be sent the same way to a sharepoint calendar? I notice an incoming email option but wonder if it can handle invites and post them on the calendar correctly. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

No.  Managing meeting requests from SharePoint does not work as you would think.  See second paragraph [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-and-update-a-sharepoint-calendar-HA010081987.aspx#BM4).

Your best bet is to use Outlook to send out meeting requests and synch these events back to SharePoint.

Even when you use Outlook to manage a meeting request and synch the meeting to SharePoint, you still come across issues, for example with meeting workspaces:

1)  Whenever a recurring event changes (a recurrence exception), the meeting workspace for the original recurring event gets orphaned.

2)  Changing attendees in Outlook doesn't always get updated in SharePoint.